# Error returning List<T> in method

Tags: c#, linq

I am using Entity Framework and LinQ using get List from two tables. This is my code:

```
public List<tbl_KidsMagazines> km_GetListJoins()
{
    var resultsList = (from s in AgEntities.tbl_KidsMagazines 
                       join sa in AgEntities.tbl_UserMaster 
                       on s.CreatedBy equals sa.User_IndexID 
                       select new { s, sa }).ToList();
    return resultsList;
}
```

But I am getting the below error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<Solution.Bussines.Entities.tbl_KidsMagazines>`

Comment: as the compiler said, `new { s, sa }` is NOT implicitly convertible to  
`tbl_KidsMagazines`. So what's your question?

Comment: I need all the values from the two Tables.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a list of *anonymous types* but your return type is `List<tbl_KidsMagazines>`, so you must create a list of `tbl_KidsMagazines` instead of anonymous types in your query.Something like this should work:

```
var resultsList = (from s in AgEntities.tbl_KidsMagazines
                   join sa in AgEntities.tbl_UserMaster 
                       on s.CreatedBy equals sa.User_IndexID 
                   select new { s, sa })
                  .AsEnumerable()
                  .Select(x => new tbl_KidsMagazines { // set properties })
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: I can try the above code but the properties get error                          var resultsList = (from s in AgEntities.tbl_KidsMagazines
                   join sa in AgEntities.tbl_UserMaster 
                       on s.CreatedBy equals sa.User_IndexID 
                   select new { s, sa })
                  .AsEnumerable()
                  .Select(x => new tbl_KidsMagazines {kmID,kmName })// set properties })
                  .ToList();                                                                              the error the name 'kmName' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Raja you should set the properties like this, for example: `new tbl_KidsMagazines { Id = x.sa.User_IndexID ,  = x.s.Name .. }`

Answer (score 0):

Set the return type to an object.

The return type of your method is `List<tbl_KidsMagazines>`

while in code you are returning Mix of two tables whose type has not been declared anywhere i.e. it is an anonymous type.